# Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier in PHP

Tags: php, regex

This is my first try at regex in PHP. I would like to use regex in PHP to match sentences that contains two set of words. I have tested it like below but it's not working

```
$regex= (red|green|round|sweet)[^.]*(apple|apples)    
$sentence = "I have two red apples."

if(preg_match($regex, $sentence)) 
{
    echo 'MATCH!!!';
} else {
    echo 'No MATCH!!!';
}
```

I am getting an error message in PHP.

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier [
```

Comment: `$regex= "/(red|green|round|sweet)[^.]*(apple|apples)/";` - Plus, if you tested as you said what you posted, should have thrown a parse error to start.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tested the regex and it works. Just not in php. For some reasons it's complaining about the [ ]

Comment: Your posted question is missing semi-colons on two lines, missing quotes and identifier for the first. Which I tested and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, this is tested and working, where you left out the quotes and identifiers for the first line and missing semi-colons on two lines.

```
<?php
$regex= "/(red|green|round|sweet)[^.]*(apple|apples)/";
$sentence = "I have two red apples.";

if(preg_match($regex, $sentence))
{
    echo 'MATCH!!!';
} else {
    echo 'No MATCH!!!';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested the regex separately. I didn't think that all it needs is a "/" in front and back.

Comment: @Cryssie You're welcome Cryssie. The `/` identifiers are required when executed via PHP.

Answer (score 2):

PHP regex must separate character.

```
$regex = '/(red|green|round|sweet)[^.]*(apple|apples)/';
```

`/` is separate character in this case.